# how to extract javascript variables by using python bs4

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<script type="text/javascript">var csrfMagicToken = "sid:bf8be784734837a64a47fcc30b9df99,162591180";var csrfMagicName = "__csrf_magic";</script>
```

The above script tag is from a webpage.

```
script = soup.find_all('script')[5]
```

By using the above line of code I was able to extract the script tag which I want but I need to extract the value of variables in a python script,I am using BeautifulSoup in my python script to extract the data.

Comment: What's the url please?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use

```
(?:var|let)\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/RJBmP0/1/).

---

**Note:** However, there are a couple of drawbacks in general to using regular expressions on code. E.g. with the above, sth. like `let x = -10;` would not be matched but would be totally valid `JavaScript` code. Also, single quotes are not supported (yet) - it totally depends on your actual input.

---

That being said, you could go for:

```
(?:var|let)\s+
(?P<key>\w+)\s*=\s*
(['"])?(?(2)(?P<value1>.+?)\2|(?P<value2>[^;]+))
```

See [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/T80F3E/1/).

---

This still leaves you helpless against escaped quotes like `let x = "some \" string";` or against variable declarations in comments. In general, favour a parser solution.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I converted the "script"  to string and used string slicing,this worked for me